# Use VNC to get right-click on touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, vnc

I found that when I use a Windows VNC client to connect to my Pi, it has a very nice emulation of right click, middle click, etc.

The functionality I cannot get from my normal touchscreen setup:

- Pi 3b
- Stretch
- 7" HDMI touchscreen

When I connect my Pi's VNC client to my Pi VNC server (127.0.0.1) I get the infinity problem. (infinitely repeated windows of self)

When I start a virtual desktop (vncserver-virtual) and then pint the VNC client to 127.0.0.1:1 it seems to, sort-of work, except for the following error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
```

Oh- and the VNC client on the Pi seems to lack the very nice touch screen trick :(

Am I chasing a red herring?

Comment: Are you trying to get right-click to work on the touchscreen or on VNC? I'm not clear on what the question is.

Comment: I want right click to work on the touch screen. 

Since I haven't yet seen anyone with a working solution, I was hoping to use a loopback vnc client- since RealVNC has implemented a click-and-hold solution.